# How to create a Yeoman base class?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'd like to be able to use a base class that provides general functionality for my Yeoman classes to use. Something like:

```
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');

class MyCustomGenerator extends Generator {
  writing() { /* overridable code here */ }
  end() { /* overridable code here */ }
}

module.exports = class extends MyCustomGenerator { /* Custom behavior here */ }
```

However, when I do this, yeoman functions in `MyCustomGenerator` like **writing** and **end** do not get called.

I looked at the Yeoman source code and found Yeoman only looks at the properties of the extended class: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/index.js#L398

What is the best way to extend the yeoman Generator class so that I can provide some default behavior that can be overridden by subclasses?

---

Notes: I found that running the following strange code will add the function to the child's prototype and the child generator will inherit the behavior as expected:

```
class MyCustomGenerator extends Generator {
  constructor() {
    super();
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).writing = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).writing;
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).end = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).end;
  }

  writing() { /* overridable code here */ }
  end() { /* overridable code here */ }
}
```

Comment: It works, but they don't seem to be executed in the order I want. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @MrFT do you mean the execution order of `writing` and `end`? I haven't noticed anything running out of order.